# Force re-render of svg part in updatepanel in async call?

Tags: c#, ajax, svg, webforms, updatepanel

I have web forms c# application. There's an svg figure that has various parts. Each part corresponds to an object of

```
public class Room
{
    public string uuid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm asynchronously calling a service to stream data to the application, this works on its own. Based on each data point I receive, I need to colour a part of the svg in a certain colour.

The initial view of the page should display the svg as white and then using a postback (a button) it needs to begin streaming using the async method.

Button code:

```
protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Room room in rooms)
        {
            await Colour(room);
        }
    }
```

Colour function:

```
//... initialisation of the call
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
     while (!reader.EndOfStream)
     {
     var currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
     if (currentLine.Length > 0)
     {
      JObject json = JObject.Parse(currentLine);
      HtmlGenericControl control = (HtmlGenericControl)FindControl(room.name);
      control.Attributes["style"] = "fill: rgb(0, 255, 0);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)";
      UpdatePanel1.Update(); //This doesn't do anything
      }
}}
```

Markup (rect id corresponds to room.name):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
<ContentTemplate>
<div> 
<svg  id="svgFloor1" runat="server">
<rect runat="server" id="e206061" style="fill:rgb(255, 255, 255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
<rect runat="server" id="e20604b1" style="fill:rgb(255, 255, 255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I cannot push html updates to the UpdatePanel. So I added a timer to it and have it check for updates every 1 second. Meanwhile all changes are generated as objects inside the async call. When the timer ticks, all of them are applied.

```
static List<Change> changes = new List<Change>();
class Change
    {
        public string control{ get; set; }
        public string style { get; set; }
    }

protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Change c in changes)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl control = (HtmlGenericControl)FindControl(c.room);
            control.Attributes["style"] = c.style;
        }
        changes = new List<Change>();
    }
```